# Switch Statement Inside a method of another class

Tags: java, class, methods, switch-statement

```
public int alphCheck(char check){
    switch(check){
        case 'a':
            return 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
            return 2;
            break;
        case 'c':
            return 3;
            break;
        case 'd':
            return 4;
            break;
        case 'e':
            return 5;
            break;
        case 'f':
            return 6;
            break;
        case 'g':
            return 7;
            break;
        case 'h':
            return 8;
            break;
        case 'i':
            return 9;
            break;
        case 'j':
            return 10;
            break;
        case 'k':
            return 11;
            break;
        case 'l':
            return 12;
            break;
        case 'm':
            return 13;
            break;
        case 'n':
            return 14;
            break;
        case 'o':
            return 15;
            break;
        case 'p':
            return 16;
            break;
        case 'q':
            return 17;
            break;
        case 'r':
            return 18;
            break;
        case 's':
            return 19;
            break;
        case 't':
            return 20;
            break;
        case 'u':
            return 21;
            break;
        case 'v':
            return 22;
            break;
        case 'w':
            return 23;
            break;
        case 'x':
            return 24;
            break;
        case 'y':
            return 25;
            break;
        case 'z':
            return 26;
            break;

    }
}
```

PS.This was done in another class
I want to be able to use this method in the main class, to input a letter, and return a number/index for that letter.
But I kept getting: this method must return a result of type int.

Very Confused. Please help. Thx.

Comment: What happens when the `check` does not match any of the `case`s?  What should the method `return` then?

Comment: That is very long. Much simpler is `check - 'a' + 1`. This works because of [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Editing your question like that seems inappropriate to me: now, the folks who were helpful enough to answer your question look foolish for not noticing you've already got a `default:` label, when in fact you did not have that at the time they answered.

Comment: As it currently stands, I would suggest making the method `static`, so that it can be called as `Classname.alphCheck(someChar)` if it is in class `Classname`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a question to consider: What happens if the inputted letter isn't one of the cases you described?

While *you* may know that you're only feeding in letters, the compiler doesn't know that, and because it can't figure out what to return if one of the cases you defined isn't hit, emits an error as a result. You'll need to put in a `default` case, so the compiler knows that the method is guaranteed to return something:

```
switch(check) {
    case 'a':
    ...
    default: 
        // return something or maybe print/throw an error
}
```

A better solution for this may be to use the fact that `chars` are just numbers in a different form. For example, `'a'` is equivalent to the integer `97` (check out the table [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for a table of characters and their ASCII numerical equivalents). So you can do a math trick to get equivalent results:

```
public int alphCheck(char check) {
    return check - 'a' + 1;
}
```

Comment: @ddgg007: In response to your edit, think about what the `return` statement does. The `return` statement tells the program to go back to the calling method with that value, right? So how can any code after the `return` be executed?

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide return type like return 0; at the end of your switch statement.or in default: case

```
switch(check) {
    ..
    default: 
        return 0;
}
```